# google forms prepopulate auto-increment id

Tags: google-forms

Trying to get a google form to perform a neat trick. I need the form to pull the last entry ID(a field in the spreadsheet) and auto-increment it. I need the auto-incremented ID to display in the form for client reference. So I need a pre-populated auto-incremented # before form submit.

Any suggestions?